# Comparing data to data in two columns in another data frame to fill third column in the first data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My newbie's struggles with pandas continue, so I would like to ask.

I have two excel files which look like this:

| id | name | group | lang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 1 |  |
| 2 | azul | 1 |  |
| 3 | rojo | 2 |  |
| 4 | red | 2 |  |
| 5 | green | 3 |  |
| 6 | verde | 3 |  |
| 7 | yellow | 4 |  |

Column name may have values that are not present in Spanish and English columns of the second excel file while columns Spanish and English may have values that are not present in column name. I want to however much all possible values.

My second file looks like this:

| english | spanish | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blue | azul | 1 |
| red | rojo | 2 |
| green | verde | 3 |

What I want to do is to fill the last column of the first dataframe with values, so it looks like this:

| id | name | group | lang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 1 | en |
| 2 | azul | 1 | sp |
| 3 | rojo | 2 | sp |
| 4 | red | 2 | en |
| 5 | green | 3 | en |
| 6 | verde | 3 | sp |
| 7 | yellow | 4 |  |

I have been trying this code, but it doesn't work:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['group'], value_vars=['en', 'sp'], value_name='lan')
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='lang', right_on='lan')[['name', 'group', 'lang']]
```

Comment: Does it require in the same group number in both df1 and df2 in order to be regarded as a match ?  There would have different sets of possible solutions for whether this requirement / restriction is needed.

Comment: Found some case that mandate us to match also `group` in matching df1 and df2.  See my edit below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` and `.isin()`:

```
df["lang"] = np.where(
    df["name"].isin(df2["english"]),
    "en",
    np.where(df["name"].isin(df2["spanish"]), "sp", ""),
)
```

Prints:

```
   id    name  group lang
0   1    blue      1   en
1   2    azul      1   sp
2   3    rojo      2   sp
3   4     red      2   en
4   5   green      3   en
5   6   verde      3   sp
6   7  yellow      4
```

Comment: This solution does not match `group` number and may cause false match (e.g. mistakenly match 'en' when it is 'sp' or vice versa, in some case.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['red', 'rojo', 2], ['blue', 'azul', 1]],  columns = ['english', 'spanish', 'group'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['red', 2], ['blue', 1], ['azul', 1]],  columns = ['name', 'group'])
```

You can do sth like this:

```
eng_df = pd.merge(df2, df, how='inner', left_on=['group', 'name'], right_on=['group','english'] )
eng_df['leng'] = 'en'
sp_df = pd.merge(df2, df, how='inner', left_on=['group', 'name'], right_on=['group','spanish'] )
sp_df['leng'] = 'sp'
eng_df.append(sp_df)[['name','group','leng']].reset_index()
```

[Checkout output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9EEp.png)

Maybe not the most strightforward solution, but at least it works.

You can skip join on 'group' if not needed but I thought it is important since you mentioned it in an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join on column `group` and then set up column `lang` according to column `name` match with which language:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='group')
```

Resulting df1:

```
   id    name  group lang english spanish
0   1    blue      1         blue    azul
1   2    azul      1         blue    azul
2   3    rojo      2          red    rojo
3   4     red      2          red    rojo
4   5   green      3        green   verde
5   6   verde      3        green   verde
6   7  yellow      4          NaN     NaN
```

Then set up column `lang` as follows:

```
df1['lang'] = np.where(df1['name'] == df1['english'], 'en', df1['lang'])
df1['lang'] = np.where(df1['name'] == df1['spanish'], 'sp', df1['lang'])
```

Resulting df1:

```
   id    name  group lang english spanish
0   1    blue      1   en    blue    azul
1   2    azul      1   sp    blue    azul
2   3    rojo      2   sp     red    rojo
3   4     red      2   en     red    rojo
4   5   green      3   en   green   verde
5   6   verde      3   sp   green   verde
6   7  yellow      4          NaN     NaN
```

You can then clean up `english` and `spanish` columns as follows:

```
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['english', 'spanish'])
```

Resulting df1:

```
   id    name  group lang
0   1    blue      1   en
1   2    azul      1   sp
2   3    rojo      2   sp
3   4     red      2   en
4   5   green      3   en
5   6   verde      3   sp
6   7  yellow      4
```

### Edit:  Is matching `group` necessary ?

There are some English and Spanish words with same spelling but different meanings.  For example,

- [pie (Spanish) = foot (English)](https://translate.google.com/?sl=es&tl=en&text=pie&op=translate), and
- [pie (English) = tarta (Spanish)](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=es&text=pie%0A&op=translate)

Therefore, in df2, we might have:

| english | spanish | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pie | tarta | 5 |
| foot | pie | 6 |

While, in df1, 'pie' is actually in group 6:

| id | name | group | lang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | pie | 6 |  |

So, **if we don't match also `group`, we might mistakenly take the English 'pie' in df2 group 5 while it actually is Spanish 'pie' (= foot in English) in df2 group 6.**